# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 1 of 4)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1919 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are four entries that need to be reviewed.

*Note: It looks like the first three are all one note. But I can see changes in hand writing and a " in the left hand column at the start of each new note. As a result I am treating them as distinct. Again, this one does not end with "El Comandante Major" or anything.*

Here is the first one:
[image]

The transcription so far:

> Con el no. 77081 aprobar las Intervención Gral. [General] de Guerra a
> este indo. [individuo] su nuevo improviso reditándote en el estado de la
> tercia xxx del año anterior 350 pts. [pesetas] de nota final del
> compromiso anterior y 125 de entrada del actual xxx contrades recibió
> coba los haberos de febrero.

---

#### Translation

Here is the translation based on the answer:

> With no. 77081 the Intervention General of War approves this
> individual his new commitment, crediting him in the statement of the
> third quarter of the previous year with 350 pesetas for the final
> instalment of the previous commitment and 125 for the entry of the
> current one, which amounts he received with the February pay.

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 2 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39500/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 3 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39502/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 4 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39504/28260)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it. Let me fix some words a bit

> Con el no. 77081 **aprueba la** Intervención Gral. [General] de Guerra a
> este indo. [individuo] su nuevo **compromiso** **acreditándole** en el estado **del tercer trimestre** del año anterior 350 pts. [pesetas] de **cuota** final del
> compromiso anterior y 125 de entrada del actual, **cuyas cantidades** recibió
> **con** los **haberes** de febrero.

His reenlistment is approved and he received some late payments.

Comment: Thank you. When I am back home I will work on the translation.

Comment: I have updated the question with the translation.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Looks correct to me