# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 2 of 4)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1919 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are four entries that need to be reviewed.

Here is (what I consider to be) the second one:

[image]

This is the transcribed text:

> Por disposición del Sr. [Señor] 1a Jefe de la Comandancia ha sido xxx
> este indo. [individuo] a pestar sus servicios al puesta de Algadilla
> (?) al que se incorporó el día 17 de Marzo.

I don't think that I have interpreted the location correctly. I just used a recent town we had transcribed from previous notes.

---

#### Translation

The translation based on the answer:

> By order of the 1st Chief of Command, this individual has been
> assigned to serve at the Algámitas post, which he joined on 17 March.

I don't know if this is the first time this has happened, but DeepL has dropped the word Señor for some reason. This might have happened before. Thoughts?

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 1 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39497/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 3 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39502/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 4 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39504/28260)

Comment: Probably the Sr. treatment has been dropped because is not idiomatic in English. "The Mr. 1st Chief of Command" sounds right to you? I'm not sure about that, just guessing

Comment: True, it does not sound right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new tranfer, this time to [Algámitas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alg%C3%A1mitas). You've got a few minor typos.

> Por disposición del Sr. [Señor] 1a Jefe de la Comandancia ha sido **destinado**
> este indo. [individuo] a **prestar** sus servicios al **puesto** de **Algámitas**
> al que se incorporó el día 17 de Marzo.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the question with my translation and observation.