# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 3 of 4)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1919 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are four entries that need to be reviewed.

Here is (what I consider to be) the third one:

[image]

This is the transcribed text:

> Según relación publicada en el xxx del Cuerpo no 146  de fecha 16 de
> Octubre año marginal con xxx a este individuo derecho para xxx a la
> xxx de Córdoba en concentración (?) de agresión tés y cuando fin tuvo
> le xxx.

I am not sure on the abbreviation, if it is **D. O.** (a bulletin) or **B. something or other**.

---

#### Translation

This is the translation based on the answer:

> According to the list published in the B.O. [Official Gazette] of the
> Corps no. 146 of 16 October, this individual was granted the right to
> move to the Cordoba Command as an applicant and when it corresponds to
> him in turn.

I am not sure if the last few words are phrased correctly?

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 1 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39497/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 2 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39500/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 4 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39504/28260)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions

> Según relación publicada en el **B.O** [Boletín Oficial] del Cuerpo nº 146 de fecha 16 de
> Octubre año marginal **concede** a este individuo derecho para **pasar** a la
> **Comandancia** de Córdoba en **concurrencia de aspirante** y cuando **por turno**
> le **corresponda**.

I haven't found an online copy of that bulletin. In this context "Cuerpo" means "Guardia Civil" meaning that you have to search for the "Boletín Oficial de la Guardia Civil".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added the translation to my question with my observations. See what you think.

Comment: As for the **Boletin Oficial** it seems like there are current ones for 2020 and 2021 here: https://www.uniongc.org/boletin-oficial-guardia-civil/ but I don't know about these older ones. Would it be worth me writing a letter to then Civil Guard head office Madrid to inquire about this?

Comment: Also, does this basically mean that we moved from Algámitas to Cordoba on 16 October 1919? Perhaps the final note for 1919 (which I will do tomorrow) will clarify. After all, this note only says "he was granted the right" at this stage.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle No, this text doesn't mean that he was transferred directly but that he was registered in a list of applicants (aspirantes) waiting his turn (cuando por turno le corresponda).

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I don't think that the full list of applicants is so relevant to ask for it

Comment: BTW when I said about writing the head office, it was a generic comment to ask them if all the old BO volumes are available anywhere.