# Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 4 of 4)

Tags: identificación-de-término

For the year 1919 in my great-grandfathers Civil Guard records there are four entries that need to be reviewed.

Here is (what I consider to be) the fourth one:

[image]

This is the first time that it closes with **El Comandante Major** again. The transcribed text so far:

> Por Circular de xxx fecha 20 de Ocbre. [Octubre] “[D. O. no. 240](http://www.bibliotecavirtualdefensa.es/BVMDefensa/es/catalogo_imagenes/grupo.do?path=11350)” xx
> destinado este ind<sup>o</sup> [individuo] a la Comandancia de Córdoba causando
> altxxx la 3<sup>a</sup> Compa. [Compañía] siendo destinado al puesto de objeto
> xxx **incorporo** el 21 de nobre. [Noviembre] y finió el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

I can see my great-grandfather listed on page 9! see:

[image]

I don't know if there is any other additional info in that buletin that relates to this note. Thanks for reviewing my transcribed text / translation.

Question: Why does it say **Otro** in the column? I understand that word to mean **Other**. I understand **Idem** over on the right which kind of means **ditto**. Looking forther up the column I see **Córdoba**.  But *Otro*? As far as I understand it my great-grandfather continues in *Civil Guard Class 2* until *1 July 1932* when he moves to *Class 1*.

---

#### Buletin

I looked on page 8 and saw a small article :

[image]

I tried translating it too for background information, but the translation is not correct:

> Directorate General of the Civil Guard
>
> Destinations
>
> The colonels
> sub-inspectors of the tercios and first chiefs of the exempt commands,
> will provide for the respective discharge and discharge in the next
> commissary review, of the guardsmen, buglers and trumpets that are
> expressed in the following list, which begins with Luciano Alcarez
> Cuadrado and ends with Santos Crespo Revilla. Madrid 20 October 1919.

---

#### Translation

This is the translation based on the answer provided:

> By Circular from
> H.E. (His Excellency The Director General) dated 20th October "D. O.
> nº 240" this individual was assigned to the Cordoba Command and was
> discharged in the 3rd Company and assigned to the post of Obejo where
> he joined on 21st November and finished the year.
>
> The Major Commander

---

### Related Questions

- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 1 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39497/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 2 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39500/28260)
- [Transcribing Spanish Civil Guard notes for 1919 (note 3 of 4)](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/39502/28260)

Comment: Out of curiosity: how many notes do you have in total? This is going to be of great of inspiration to see the history of Spain in the first third of the 20th century

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' My great-grandfathers records here is a 21 page document from 1902 when he started in the miliatry up to 1936. Does that help? When I started this "task" I originally began with a 1930 note but then decided it best to systematically work through bit by bit from page 1.

Comment: Does the "Otro" column have a header? Without that, it is going to be difficult to know what "otro" refers to...

Comment: @wimi Yes - "Clases". I see words like **Guardio 2** etc there.

Comment: Great, I am looking forward to seeing the 1930s documents.

Comment: Then either your great-grandfather belonged to a different class that is not one of the options in that list, or whoever made the document considered that column unimportant and entered "Other" for many people instead of finding out what their class was...

Comment: @wimi Looking at the table, it seems that "Otro" is equivalent to double quotes.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOstopharming' Just to let you know that it seems as my great-grandfather got closer to retirement that his activities reduced. Several of the notes are similar in nature. There are still a handful that I need to discuss (like his promotion in 1932) and others. We already did 1930 notes which had the acknowledgement from the KIng. But I don't see any excursions for crowd control from now on. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestions

> Por Circular de **S.E (Su Excelencia El Director General)** fecha 20 de Ocbre. [Octubre] “D. O. nº 240” **es**
> destinado este indº [individuo] a la Comandancia de Córdoba causando
> **alta en** la 3ª Compa. [Compañía] siendo destinado al puesto de **[Obejo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obejo)**
> **al que se** incorpor**ó** el 21 de nobre. [Noviembre] y finió el año.
>
> El Comandante Mayor

Not sure about the **S.E**

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate the link to the location. I have updated my question with the translation.

Comment: So **Córdoba** must be quite a large area if it has posts within in, like **Obejo**.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Córdoba is one of the eight provinces that form Andalucía in the South of Spain: Huelva, Cádiz, Sevilla, Málaga, Almería, Córdoba, Jaen y Granada.

Comment: Thanks for that extra insight.

Comment: Happy with translation?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I think that it's pretty good